# XML DataTable contents into class

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, dataset

This stuff confuses me, but I'll explain best I can.
I have an XML file containing users, and I need to load the users into a "User" class which looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string userID;
    public string pass;
    public bool banned;
    public bool online;
    public IPAddress lastIp;
    public bool admin;
    public Job currentJob; //another class just like the user class. the job will be loaded just like the users - from xml.
}
```

and the XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<User_Table>
  <User>
    <Username>Example</Username>
    <PasswordHash>This will be hashed</PasswordHash>
    <Banned>false</Banned>
    <LastLoginIP>localhost</LastLoginIP>
    <CurrentJob>Null</CurrentJob>
    <Admin>false</Admin>
  </User>
</User_Table>
```

how do I loop through the XML file and load each User into a User class (all of them will be stored in a List = new List(); so they can be checked quickly)
I have searched around quite a bit, and I just can't figure out how to do it.
I have a DataSet for the users, which a datagridview displays.

Comment: If you have a DataTable, why a class and collection too?

Comment: The User class is for looping through quickly without reading from disk. The datatable is for display (UI) and the List is for looping through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple way to deserialize your XML by the `XmlSerializer`. First you have to capsule your properties:

```
public class User
{
    public string userID { get; set; }
    public string pass { get; set; }
    public bool banned { get; set; }
    public bool online { get; set; }
    public IPAddress lastIp { get; set; }
    public bool admin { get; set; }
    public Job currentJob { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use the `XmlSerializer` like

```
User DeserializedUser;
XmlSerializer Deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User));
FileStream Fs = new FileStream("UserFile.xml", FileMode.Open);
DeserializedUser = (User)Deserializer.Deserialize(Fs);
```

Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552731(v=vs.120).aspx) for more information. You are also possible to serialize your whole collection like

```
List<User> DeserializedUsers;
using (StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader("UserFile.xml"))
{
    XmlSerializer Deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<User>), new XmlRootAttribute("User_Table"));
    DeserializedUsers = (List<User>)Deserializer.Deserialize(Sr);
}
```

**EDIT:**
The name of your properties have not to be the same like in your XML-file. You can set the `ElementName` like

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Username")]
public string userID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do the variables of the User class need to be named the same thing as in the XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<User> users =  doc.Descendants("User").Select(x => new User() {
                userID = (string)x.Element("Username"),
                pass = (string)x.Element("PasswordHash"),
                banned = (bool)x.Element("Banned"),
                lastIp = Dns.GetHostAddresses((string)(x.Element("LastLoginIP"))).FirstOrDefault(),
                currentJob = x.Elements("CurrentJob").Select(y => new Job()
                {
                    name = (string)y.Element("name")
                }).FirstOrDefault(),
                admin = (bool)x.Element("Admin")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public string userID { get; set; }
        public string pass { get; set; }
        public bool banned { get; set; }
        public bool online;
        public IPAddress lastIp { get; set; }
        public bool admin { get; set; }
        public Job currentJob { get; set; } //another class just like the user class. the job will be loaded just like the users - from xml.
    }
    public class Job
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

}
```